# How to display input values to ionic grid?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I am trying to do this, I want to pass the value from my input to my ionic grid. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this? Thank you for answering.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get first name value and last name value as form data. Then add it to an array. In Html side you can loop that array and value can add to the rows of grid.

Check this angular tutorial to get clear idea

https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-input-values-and-binding

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should learn angular instead of ionic/react, here is why...**

[the following is a personal opinion from personal experience]

I started learning ionic react but by the time I had finished the documentation and my project, I left having learned nothing. This half full feeling. It was odd that I couldn't fully grasp a simple object class container language as I program almost every day of the year for fun. I couldn't figure it out, it bugged me for a while but I took the L.

a few months pass and then I begin learning Angular as a second attempt at hybrid PWAs.

Having used Angular and Ionic/React, Angular blows Ionic/React out of the water when it comes to learning and understanding the material. Angular s docs are well orchestrated and the framework is as enjoyable as it is popular.

**Comparing Official docs between Angular and Ionic.**

- Ionic/react documentation demos were outdated making it impossible to follow the example code vs the interactive demo
- Ionic/react documentation is unreliable. at the time it was a gamble between 'updated', 'outdated','missing-information' (makes it impossible to build a proper project)
- Angular's documentation is updated, accurate, thorough and overall superb
- Angular has a greater online presence with an active online community, Q and A.
- Easier to work with, less headaches, constant updates

Ionic documentation is a travel brochure.
Angular documentation is a map.
If you are going hiking in the woods, do you want a map or a travel brochure?

Posted some links below.

https://angular.io/docs
Covers all topics, demos are accurate

https://material.angular.io/components/categories
Ready Components